# Scala: porting a java interface to scala

Tags: java, scala, traits

I have a piece of Java code as follows:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.PARAMETER;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;


@BindingAnnotation
@Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface MessageCount {
}
```

This is not my code, but I am trying rewrite this in Scala. I do not understand the @interface construct very well. Nor do I understand how those annotations can be translated over to Scala.
Or is it possible to use this in Scala somehow?

I prefer rewriting/porting this in Scala. The only thing I can think of is to write it as a Scala trait.

Any pointers, suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: It's not interface. It's java `annotation`. I'm not sure it may be correctly ported to scala.

Answer (score 1):

No, currently annotations with `@Retention(RUNTIME)` can't be written in Scala.

> Or is it possible to use this in Scala somehow?

Yes, you can use it in Scala. You can have both Scala and Java code in the same project (Java code normally goes to `src/main/java`, Scala code to `src/main/scala`), and they can even refer to each other.

Comment: That is good news. Can you show me how this can be done in an example? Do I have to use the javaconversions package somehow? How can I use this in a Scala

Comment: No, you don't need to do anything special. Just use `@MessageCount` in your Scala code in the same way you would in Java. Except you may need to specify whether you want to annotate a field or a method, see http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.annotation.meta.package.

Comment: How can i use @Retention (Runtime) then?